# Idiomatic expression for "absorbed in prayer"

Tags: collocation

I'm trying to convey an Italian expression  the best I can in English which roughly goes *absorbed in prayer*  but I guess it really sounds odd.

Can anyone suggest anything better?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give more details?   A sentence where you'd use the phrase might help.

Comment: Actually, the literal translation you offered might be just fine.  I hedge, however, because it may be that the Italian expression has different meaning or connotation than the English version would be understood to have.  This is where an example sentence would help.

Comment: "I did not want to interrupt him as he seemed to be deeply absorbed in prayer" sounds perfectly fine to me. Perhaps the addition of "deeply" helps to smooth out the translation?

Comment: Sara, it's good to give your post a meaningful title e.g. **idiomatic expression for "absorbed in prayer"** as that's more noticeable and clearer in the forum list view.

Comment: @k1eran - I've taken your advice and edited Sara's title for this question. +1

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestions. I apologize for leaving out some context which would have helped. The example you have given perfectly fits though. Next time I will also give some clearer title to my post.

Comment: Perhaps "meditating" carries some of the connotations you're looking for?